# Get the correct days in vacation accumulation report

Tags: sql

I need acculate how many days between today and Employee hiredate(but do not care the year). That mearn if one employee hire in 07/1/2012, i want to get a result is today 07/15/2013-07/1/2013, that is 15 days. I do not need the hire year 2012.

i play around with the dateadd and datediff but just did not get the correct result.

```
SELECT 
    Co Employee, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    dateadd(dd,  DATEDIFF(dd,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,0),HireDate)
FROM dbo.PREH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit brute force, perhaps, but it seems to work.  The idea is to add a number of years to the hiredate, then to check that against the current date.  When it is greater, use one fewer years:

```
select (case when DATEADD(year, datediff(year, hiredate, getdate()), hiredate) < GETDATE()
             then DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(year, datediff(year, hiredate, getdate()), hiredate), getdate())
             else DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(year, datediff(year, hiredate, getdate()) - 1, hiredate), getdate())
        end)
from preh;
```

The problem is that `datediff()` with `year` returns the number of times that the year boundary is crossed, not the number of years between two dates as a span.  So, there is one year between 2012-12-30 and 2013-01-01, and there is one year between 2012-01-01 and 2013-12-31.

Comment: Thank you so much. that works for me. but just as you said i may have problem with the year boutdary crossed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use modulus division:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,'20120101',GETDATE())%365
```

The downside is that you're treating leap year the same as every other year, which you could handle with case logic.

In your code:

```
SELECT 
    Co Employee, 
    LastName, 
    FirstName, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,HireDate,GETDATE())%365 AS DaysThisYear
FROM dbo.PREH
```

Comment: This will make me change the code every year. and also make all the employee the same result. I need calculate the days according to the each employee's hire date, just do not care about the year

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're dropping the year just as part of formatting the output. Formatting shouldn't affect the underlying data though. The last element of your tuple should be:

```
datediff(day, HireDate, getdate())
```

That way you can do arithmetic on the data, and save the formatting for downstream, when it's needed.